# query to fetch the average number of transactions a customer has been made

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which is having 3 tables :

```
 Table Name: allowed_users Columns: Id (int) primary, date_joined(datetime)

 Table Name: profile_data Columns: user_id(int) primary, age (int), gender(varchar)

 Table Name: transaction_data Columns: user_id(int) primary, transaction_name(varchar), 
               number_transactions(int),day_of_transaction(date)primary
```

I want to fetch the average number of transactions done by a user everyday by their gender for allowed users only.

I tries this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  p.gender,
  AVG(t.number_transactions)
FROM allowed_users AS a
JOIN profile_data AS p
  ON a.id = p.user_id
JOIN transaction_data AS t
  ON t.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY gender
```

I am not getting how to calculate this on the daily basis.

Please suggest me how to calculate it on the daily basis.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: add the date to your group by

Comment: select a.id,p.gender,AVG(t.number_transactions) 
from allowed_users as a 
join profile_data as p on a.id = p.user_id 
join transaction_data as t on t.user_id = p.user_id 
group by p.gender, t.day_of_transaction.      @JacobA. like this?

Comment: @ra_pri In transaction_data table user_id column should not primary it should contain the value of id column from allowed_users right?

Comment: @SantoshDahifale Yeah you are right but the question is in this way only, in my paper.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this you will get average transaction done by user and its gender.

```
SELECT allowed_users.id, profile_data.gender, 
(COUNT(transaction_data.id)/COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_data.day_of_transaction)) AS
 averageTransactions 
FROM allowed_users 
INNER JOIN profile_data ON allowed_users.id =profile_data.user_id 
INNER JOIN transaction_data ON allowed_users.id=transaction_data.userId 
GROUP BY allowed_users.id, profile_data.gender
```

> And for the average transaction of the user everyday and its gender.

```
SELECT allowed_users.id, profile_data.gender, 
(COUNT(transaction_data.id)/COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_data.day_of_transaction)) AS
 averageTransactions 
FROM allowed_users 
INNER JOIN profile_data ON allowed_users.id =profile_data.user_id 
INNER JOIN transaction_data ON allowed_users.id=transaction_data.userId 
GROUP BY allowed_users.id, profile_data.gender,transaction_data.day_of_transaction
```